# Fastest KV data structures for merging unique keys?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, merge, data-processing

I currently have around 15 worker threads processing data in a CPU-bound loop. Each time a result is determined, an RW lock is obtained so the results can be stored in a shared KV structure (a hash table), unique by key.

Since a lot of time is spent obtaining the locks, I'm exploring different options to improve performance. I've played around with lock-free hash tables (concurrent_unordered_map and Intel TBB lock free structures) but have been wondering about having each thread record its results in a separate hash table and once all threads have completed, performing some sort of conflict resolution.

The conflict resolution would basically be for each [K1,V1], [K1,V2], .... [K1,Vn] should be coalesced into [K1,F(V1,V2,...Vn)].

I'm curious what data structure would be most suitable for iterating over all values of the same key from the other structures. I'm certain there has to be something better than iterating over each structure separately. Create a multimap, bulk add the separate structures, then conflict resolve, etc?

Comment: I assume that in current method a uniqueness test is made before each insertion.  If you use one hash table per thread, how will you maintain unique keys?  Or are the keys automatically all unique?

Comment: The key is a derived property of the data being processed, so it's already there. The uniqueness checking is so results can be grouped by said key.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash table that allows you direct access to its backing array, and use the same size backing array for each thread's hash table. Then when it comes time to merge the hash tables, divide up the backing arrays among the worker threads - for example, with 15 worker threads and assuming a backing array size of 1500, worker_thread_1 would iterate through each hash table's backing array from [0, 100), worker_thread_2 would iterate through each hash table's backing array from [100, 200), etc. This way each of the worker threads can perform its merge without needing to acquire any locks or communicate in any other way with the other worker threads. Directly iterating through the backing arrays will introduce some inefficiency because some of the array elements will be null (probably from 10-50% of the elements will be null depending on your hash table's load factor), but at the same time by directly iterating through the backing array you won't need to execute the hashing function which ought to make up for the inefficiency of iterating through null elements.

You need to use the same size backing array for each thread's hash table to ensure that each key hashes to the same array element (although there may be a way to correct for differently sized backing arrays when dividing up the sub-arrays among your worker thread - I just can't think of a suitable algorithm off the top of my head).

You'll also need to use a hash table that uses linked lists for collisions - a hash table that uses probing for collisions is going to complicate things too much.

You could accomplish the same thing by using an ordered map (e.g. a balanced binary tree or a skip list) and evenly dividing up the keys between the worker threads, but this isn't going to be as efficient since you'll be using O(log(n)) inserts and lookups instead of constant-time (on average) inserts and lookups with a hash table.

Comment: Very interesting approach! I like the dual-purposing of the backing arrays as both hash tables and arrays, and the ability to do the conflict resolution on multiple threads simultaneously.